# Infinite scroll model, ag-grid in angular problem

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Module ag-grid-community has no exported member RowModelType is the error im getting, https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/infinite-scrolling/ but here they do

I tried to copy the code to play with it but its not working for me is it the version of ag grid community or something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.